# Can I transfer ownership of an ERC-721 contract to a gnosis safe?

Tags: erc-721, gnosis-safe

I was sent here by the nice user support people.

Can I transfer ownership of an ERC-721 contract to a gnosis safe?

just to be clear, not erc-721 tokens... I am talking about the contract, can it be controlled by a gnosis safe address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and multiple projects do this. There are no limitations from the Safe side, but you need to ensure that your ERC-721 contract works with smart contract wallet as an owner. So the advice would be first to test it on a test network.

Comment: Can you define "work safe" or provide some`EIP`s. Asking from curiosity.

Comment: I didn't write "work safe" in my message. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

On EVM (Ethreum Virtual Machine), there isn't much of a difference functionally between a smart contract address and an externally owned address (EOA). Gnosis is a smart contract and can interact with all sorts of other smart contracts (like an ERC-721 contract). However, one key difference between a smart contract and an EOA is that a smart contract address does not have a private key, and thus can't sign data on its own. If the ERC-721 contract has implemented some sort of signature verification function that requires the owner to sign some data, then Gnosis Safe won't be able to interact with it. Most of the implementation of ERC-721 is compatible with having a smart contract as an owner. However, the specification doesn't mention much about its implementation so it is technically possible to have an ERC-721 that's not compatible with Gnosis Safe. Testing it a testnet would be the best way to make sure things would work the right way on mainnet.